# Waiting for process mainwindowhandle

Tags: process, f#, dispose

I have a UI process that I'm starting and want to close on the `IDisposable.Dispose()` method. Unfortunately it seems that calling `CloseMainWindow()` will not work immediately after starting the process because it does not have a MainWindowHandle yet. Right now I'm using a while loop to wait for it before closing but it doesn't feel very elegant. Is there a better way of doing it?

Also I've already tried `WaitForInputIdle` but it doesn't seem to work unfortunately.

```
        member x.Dispose() =
            let (ActiveClient (_, _, p)) = x
             while p.MainWindowHandle = IntPtr.Zero do
                         ()
            p.CloseMainWindow() |> ignore
```

**Edit:**

This is what I tried with `WaitForInputIdle`

```
    interface IDisposable with
        member x.Dispose() =
            let (ActiveClient (_, _, p)) = x
            p.WaitForInputIdle(5000) |> ignore
            p.CloseMainWindow() |> ignore
```

The thing about the process I'm trying to close is that, first it spawns a prompt window. Then after you press OK on that window it spawns the mainwindow. Could that be related to why it doesn't work?

Comment: What timeout are you providing when using WaitForInputIdle?  That is the preferred mechanism to do this...

Comment: I used 5000MS and it didn't seem to work :/ ..

Comment: can you show the code you tried?

Comment: Added it, with some extra comments, thanks!